# Angular ng-repeat inside directive is not rendering

Tags: angularjs, compilation, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've asked this before, but I wasn't specific enough. I have a bit of a conundrum with ng-repeat inside a nested directive. I'll have to post all my code so you can see what i'm doing as it's easier than trying to explain.

In essence, my ng-repeat is not rendering contents if I use properties bound to the controller. However if I output the property contents to the screen using {{ ctl.myarray }} it reads just fine, proving that the property is accessible.

The problem is occurring inside a directive which dynamically loads contents through ajax and $compiles it. The contents of the ajax file contains html with a directive, and THAT directive has the ng-repeat which doesn't work.

Here goes:

**Controller** (main and first nested controller)

```
<!-- main controller -->
<div ng-controller="ReportController as rc" ng-cloak="">

    <!-- controller for filters -->
    <div class="report-filters" ng-controller="FilterController as fc">

        <!-- directive that loads bootstrap popovers from a template -->
        <rep-popover parent="fc" title="Add Filter" template="html/popovers/add_filter.html">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-add">Add Filter</a>
        </rep-popover>    

    </div>

    <!-- ../ rest of the page below ... -->

</div>
```

**popover.directive.js** (popover generator directive)

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module(ng_module_name)
        .directive('repPopover', popover);

    popover.$inject = ['$http', '$compile'];

    function popover($http, $compile) {
        var directive = {
            controller: controller,
            controllerAs: 'pop',
            link: link,
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { // properties bound in html
                parent: '=',
                title: '@',
                template: '@',
                placement: '@',
                container: '@'
            }
        };

        return directive;
        //////////////////


        /** directive controller */
        function controller($scope) {
            var ctl = this;

            ctl.parent = $scope.parent;
            ctl.title = $scope.title;
            ctl.template = $scope.template;
            ctl.placement = $scope.placement;

            ctl.close = close;
            //////////////////


            /** close the popover */
            function close() {
                var popover = $scope.element.children(":last-child");
                popover.popover("hide");
            }

        }

        /** DOM manipulation function */
        function link(scope, element) {

            scope.element = element;

            if (!scope.template) {
                alert("Error: popover requested, but no template provided!");
                return;
            }

            // request template, and populate popover
            $http.get(reports_data.root+'/'+scope.template).then(function (content) {
                if (content && content.status == 200) {

                    var activator = element.children(":first-child");
                    var placement = scope.placement || "bottom";
                    var compiled_content = $compile(content.data)(scope);

                    // bootstrap popover
                    activator.popover({
                        title: scope.title,
                        content: compiled_content,
                        placement: placement,
                        html: true,
                        container: scope.container || false
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}());
```

**add_filter.html** (popover template)

```
<!--- add filter -->

<div class="add-filter-popover">
    <form>
        <select rep-filter-select="" columns="parent.tracker.available" class="form-control filter-select">
            <!-- THIS IS WHERE THE REPEAT BREAKS -->
            <option ng-repeat="i in select.list">{{ i }}</option>
        </select>

        <!-- show before column is chosen -->
        <div class="empty-spacing"></div>

        <!-- ../ rest of template... -->
    </form>

</div> <!--- ./add-filter-popover -->
```

**filter.directive.js** (the nested directive inside popover template)

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module(ng_module_name)
        .directive('repFilterSelect', filterSelect)

    filterSelect.$inject = ['$compile'];

    function filterSelect($compile) {
        var directive = {
            controller: controller,
            controllerAs: 'select',
            link: link,
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                columns: "="
            }
        };

        return directive;
        //////////////////


        /** directive controller */
        function controller($scope, $element) {
            var ctl = this;

            ctl.list = [1,2,3,4,5];
            //////////////////

        }

        /** DOM manipulation function */
        function link(scope, element) {

            // manual compile as part of a popover
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
})();
```

Where you see my comment in add_filter, these options are not being populated. If I change that to `<option ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]"></option>` then it works just fine.

Furthermore, if I output {{ select.list }} inside the select (and make the directive a div just for test purposes), the contents of select.list are correct.

Thanks to anyone willing to have a quick read :)

Comment: All looks fine on the surface, I'd love to breakpoint it and play around with it. Is it at all possible to get a jsfiddle or plnkr of this?

Comment: I think the problem is that `select.list` is not available where you'd like to access it. ControllerAs `select` is accessible inside of the template of your directive. Please have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6x1t9on/). You could probably do something with `ngTransclude` but that's making it more complicated.

Comment: @KieranDotCo I'll get one set up for you if I can't get anywhere with AWolfs suggestion. I'm a little busy so it might take me a few hours. Keep an eye out :)

Comment: @AWolf. This worked for me. However why is it not available? Are you able to explain as i'm not sure I fully understand?

Comment: _"However why is it not available?"_  Because the directive `repFilterSelect` has an isolated scope. Nothing is accessible from outside the directive.

Comment: So the contents of the directive HTML don't count as being within the scope of the directive?